# Using Annihilators and Dual Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V = C[0,1]$ and let U be the subspace of functions of the form 
$y(x) = ax+b$ for some a, b depending on the function.  Give an explicit family of functionals $F\subset U^\perp$ such that for any $y \in V$ satisfying f(y) = 0$\ \  \forall f \in F$, we have$\  y\in U$.  This is also saying, in $V^{**}$, we have$$span F^\perp\cap\phi(V) = \phi(U).$$

If anyone could help it's appreciated, thanks

Comment: This familly should work : $$\left\lbrace f_{\lambda,h} \left| f_{\lambda, h}(y) = \frac{y(\lambda+h)- y(\lambda)}{h} - (f(1)-f(0)), \lambda \in ]0,1[, \lambda+h \in [0,1] \right. \right\rbrace $$ Note that as the functions y are continous, you can make this familly countable. Edit : I forgot to substract the average slope of y ;)

Comment: Wow that's intense thanks!  That may sound like an odd question but what is the annihilator of F?  In terms of understanding that part has me stumped @Tryss

Comment: Actually, you can simplify the family, $f_h(y) = \frac{y(h)-y(0)}{h}$ should work (for h \in ]0,1]). About your question, as the space of continous function is not reflexive, the annihilator of F can have two distinct definitions : $$F^{\bot} = \left\lbrace y \in V : \forall f \in F, f(y) = 0 \right\rbrace$$ or $$F^{\bot} = \left\lbrace T \in V^{**} : \forall f \in V^*, T(f) = 0 \right\rbrace$$

Comment: I have determined that since $F\subset U^\perp$, we have that $\phi(U)=(U^\perp)^\perp\subset F^\perp$, would this be correct?

Comment: What is $\phi$ ?

Comment: Sorry, its a function $\phi(V):V->(V^*)^*$, following the mapping $v->\phi_v(f)=f(v)$

Comment: Then $\phi(U) \neq (U^{\bot})^\bot$, because there is no reflexivity. There is only an inclusion. Now, $\forall \phi_u \in \phi(U)$, we have $\forall f \in F, \phi_u(f) = f(u) = 0$, so $\phi_u \in F^{\bot}$ and your proposition is true

Comment: How did you come up with that family? @Tryss

Comment: The idea is that the linear functions are the only functions with constant slope. My first idea was to use $f(y) = y''$, but, too bad, the functions are not two time differentiable. Then, you think of $f(y) = y'-y'(0)$, but the functions are not differentiable. Then you think to use use the average slope on every point

Comment: Sorry I have been working on this question endlessly all night and I cannot figure it out.  And I don't understand the question still, I cannot solve it.  The span of $F^\perp$ makes no sense to me, and I can't justify to myself why your answer is good @Tryss, if you could provide any other explanation to this it would be appreciated but dont feel obliged as you have done a lot already